# Failed Install of SSDT for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to install SSDT for VS 2017 (15.5.1), and I get this error:

> "The requested metafile operation is not support (0x800707D3)".

The Microsoft page states that this was fixed in the current release but apparently that isn't true.  From Microsoft's change log: Fix an issue where setup fails with the following error message:

> "The requested metafile operation is not support (0x800707D3)".

I have Visual 2017 installed and working and all updates to it have been installed

I am running Windows 7 Enterprise (company machine out of my control)

Has anyone figured out a work around?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Comment: Update visual studio and see if it installs

Comment: Yep, updated VS before I posted and that didn't help

Comment: My laptop died and the new computer came with Windows 10 on it. I install VS 2017 and SSDT for 2017 and everything works fine.  Maybe the solution is to upgrade to windows 10 ....

Answer (score 1):

The method I successfully used after encountering the failure message cited above was to uninstall the Visual Studio 2015 shell using add / remove programs (Win 10 Pro); rebooting, and then reinstalling SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (Community Ed).

I am not sure how the Visual Studio 2015 Shell got installed: I previously removed all prior versions of SQL Server, and Visual Studio from the machine. I did build out the machine again by first installing SQL Server 2017 Dev, Visual Studio 2017 Comm Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, Windows 10 Ent. Ended up installing SSDT for VS2015.